# TypeError: driver.actions(...).move is not a function

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript

I am writing a selenium test in Javascript, where I want to move/hover cursor over a particular element. I tried bunch of things, but nothing seems to work -

```
1. driver.findElement(selector)
      .then(element => driver.actions().move({origin:element}).perform())
2. driver.findElement(selector)
      .then(element => driver.actions().moveToElement(element).perform())
3. driver.findElement(selector)
      .then(element => driver.actions({bridge: true}).moveMouse(element).perform())
4. driver.findElement(selector)
      .then(element => driver.actions({bridge: true}).move(element).clickAndHold().perform())
5. driver.findElement(selector)
      .then(element => driver.actions({bridge:true}).move({duration:5000,origin:element,x:0,y:0}).perform())
```

I am consuming 3.6.0 version of selenium-webdriver npm package.

Note - I am able to perform rest all driver actions like click, DoubleClick etc on that element, so essentially there are no issues in discovering that element. Just move action I am unable to perform - it is always giving `TypeError: driver.actions(...).move is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const {
    Builder,
    By,
    Key,
    until
} = require('selenium-webdriver');

let driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions( /* ... */ )
    .setFirefoxOptions( /* ... */ )
    .build();

driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=s&oq=s&aqs=chrome..69i57.210j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8").then((test) => {


    driver.wait(until.elementLocated((By.css('div[role="dialog"] iframe')), 20000)).then((elemframe) => {

        driver.switchTo().frame(elemframe).then(
            
            driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath('(//*[contains(text(),"I agree")])[1]')), 20000).then((elem) => {

                driver.actions()
                .move({
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                    origin: elem
                }).click().perform()

            }))
    })
});
```

Use latest npm release as the legacy action class doesn't have move in it .

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions_exports_LegacyActionSequence.html

else use **mouseMove**

Comment: Thanks much! This helps.

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const hoverLocation = driver.findElement(selector);
const actions = driver.actions({ bridge: true });
actions.move({ origin: hoverLocation }).perform();
```

Find your hover location, then you can perform the action over that location.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, We should change `moveElement()` to `executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)`
Here is the complete replacement:

```js
const element = await driver.findElement(...)
await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
await sleep(500);
```

And sleep function:

```js
function sleep(ms) {return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))}
```